# Helm Postgres will not bind to PVC

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, persistent-volumes, helm3, persistent-volume-claims

I'm deploying postgres DB using helm by this steps:

1. applying pv:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  namespace: admin-4
  name: postgresql-pv-admin-4
  labels:
    type: local
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  capacity:
    storage: 10Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  hostPath:
    path: "/mnt/data"
```

2. applying PVC:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  namespace: admin-4
  name: postgresql-pvc-admin-4
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 10Gi
```

3. running helm command:

```
helm install postgres bitnami/postgresql --set persistence.enabled=true --set persistence.existingClaim=postgresql-pvc-admin-4 --set volumePermissions.enabled=true -n admin-4
```

This is the output:
[image: k get pod,pv,pvc]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the latest bitnami/postgresql chart (chart version 11.8.1), the fields to set are:

```yaml
primary:
  persistence:
    enabled: true
    existingClaim: postgresql-pvc-admin-4
```